# Create animation for text field

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to create an animation in Android. I have 3 `TextView`s placed in an `LinearLayout`. All I want to do is the text field must come on to the screen as though it has been pulled out from the left end of the screen. Something similar to a marquee, however the text field must come from left end of screen one character at a time to occupy the left end of screen.

Comment: K i will.Thanks for suggestion.If u could provide me with some links were i could achieve this task.would be great

Answer (score 0):

you must textView set textview property in your xml layout `android:ellipsize="marquee"` and you `oncreate()` method to set textview like `youtextview.setSelected(true);` now your textview running with marquee effect perfectly work for me!

another way you can add dynamically textview in coding you can follow this code:

```
yourtextview.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
yourtextview.setSelected(true);
```